# golang cross compilation on mac for windows

Tags: windows, macos, go, cross-compiling

I am writing a go program to parse csv files and upload them to a postgres database in the Heroku cloud.  The program works fine on my mac laptop.  Eventual target platform for deploying the code is Windows though.  I did some research and found that the following command creates a Windows executable on my Mac.

```
 env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -v main.go
```

This produced an executable called main.exe when I had just one file called main.go.  The program has grown since then and I have it now split into three source files:

```
main.go
common.go
specific.go
```

They are all in the same source directory though.  Moreover, since the program is relatively small, I have all functions in the 'main' package.  What is the command now to cross-compile on mac for windows for multiple source files belonging to the same package?  The previous command did not work since the other two file common.go and specific.go are not included.  Also, I would like to know how to rename the Windows 'exe' file to something else than main.exe, e.g., upload.exe?  I am using go version go1.5 darwin/amd64

Comment: just build the package, and don't specify individual files.

Comment: e.g. `GOOS=windows go build -o upload.exe` (optionally, you can specify the import path of a package to build that instead of the package in the current directory).

Comment: Sorry, if this is a naive question (I am a Go beginner :), but how do you build just the "main" package?  Because that is all the three source files are in the main package.  The code lives in my home directory in the path ~/go/src/github.com/bruparel/Projects.  All the source files are under Projects.  My $GOPATH is set to '~/go'

Comment: Start here: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). You either need to have your 3 files be part of the same main package, or put them in their own package and import the common dependencies.

Comment: @JimB, Thank you.  I have now been able to get the cross platform build go without any problems.  For those who may be in the same boat as I was:  skip the -v main.go part in my original post and you will be all right, i.e., type env GOOS=window GOARCH386 go build